# getting Mixed spaces and tabs error in grunt.js, how to remove it?

Tags: gruntjs

My jshint code is:

```
 jshint: {
      options: {
        curly: true,
        eqeqeq: true,
        immed: true,
        latedef: true,
        newcap: true,
        noarg: true,
        sub: true,
        undef: true,
        boss: true,
        eqnull: true,
        browser: true
      },
      globals: {
        jQuery: true
      }
    },
```

and I am calling that as:

```
  grunt.registerTask('foo', 'lint');// For running in cmd you need grunt.cmd foo.
```

How can I overcome with this error ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could fix the mixed tabs and spaces :)

Or add the `smarttabs` option to ignore the error:

```
jshint: {
  options: {
    smarttabs: true
  }
}
```

Or if you only want to disable warnings per file, add this to the top of the files with the errors:

```
/*jshint smarttabs:true */
```

JSHint documentation: http://www.jshint.com/docs/

Comment: I only want to disable the error in comments. Can I do that?